# How to get data from .Net code-behind into mixpanel (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, .net, mixpanel

All of the examples I have seen are hard coded.
Like:

```
mixpanel.people.identify("12148");
```

How do I replace the 12148 with a value from the server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just thought of an even better way. Use StringBuilder and RegisterStartupScript.

```
Dim User As New UserViewModel(Utilities.CurrentUserID)
Dim strMixCommand As New System.Text.Stringbuilder()

strMixCommand.Append("mixpanel.track('XXXXXX.aspx Page Loaded');")
strMixCommand.Append("mixpanel.people.identify(" & User.UserID & ");"
strMixCommand.Append("mixpanel.people.set({ 'UserID':'" & User.UserID & "',"
strMixCommand.Append("'UserType':'Borrower',"
strMixCommand.Append("'$created':new Date(),"
strMixCommand.Append("'$last_login':new Date(),"
strMixCommand.Append("'$email':'" & User.Email.ToString() & "',"
strMixCommand.Append("'First Name':'" & User.FirstName.ToString() & "',"
strMixCommand.Append("'Last Name':'" & User.LastName.ToString() & "',"
strMixCommand.Append("'Member Since':'" & User.CreatedDate.ToString() & "'})"

Dim strScript As String = "<script type=""text/javascript"" language=""javascript"">" & strMixCommand & "</script>"

Me.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "Script", strScript)
```

If this was run on page load, this would generate the JavaScript on the server side, pre-populated with the desired data from the database, without the intermediate step of populating hidden fields, or having any mixpanel code in the front-end at all...

Answer (score 0):

Ok. After much experimentation I developed my own answer, and thought I would share it so any other "noobs" with the same problem would have a resource...

First - Retrieve the data from the database (on the server side) and put it in hidden fields (on the client side).  I did it like this:(in the page load event)(example is in VB)

```
Dim User As New UserViewModel(Utilities.CurrentUserID) 
hdnUserID.Value = User.UserId
hdnEmail.Value = User.Email.ToString()
hdnFirstName.Value = User.FirstName.ToString()
hdnLastName.Value = User.LastName.ToString()
hdnMemberSince.Value = User.CreatedDate.ToString()
```

Hidden fields on client side look like this: (I put them out of the way at the very bottom of the page)

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnUserID" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnEmail" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnFirstName" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnLastName" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnMemberSince" runat="server" />
```

Then in the client side Javascript (in the head), refer to the values in the hidden fields using the <% * %> method.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    mixpanel.track("XXXXXXX.aspx Page Loaded");

    mixpanel.people.identify('<% = mxpUserID.Value %>');

    mixpanel.people.set({
        "UserID": '<% = mxpUserID.Value %>',
        "User Type": "Borrower",
        "$created": new Date(),
        "$last_login": new Date(),
        "$email": '<% = mxpEmail.Value %>',
        "First Name": '<% = mxpFirstName.Value %>',
        "Last Name": '<% = mxpLastName.Value %>',
        "Member Since": '<% = mxpMemberSince.Value %>'
    });
</script>
```

This is what worked for me. MixPanels documentation is lacking (in my opinion) any real help in dot.net implementation. So there you have it. Hope it helps someone, somewhere, sometime.

While this question and answer are tagged mixpanel and pertain to my attempt to use mixpanel, the true basis of the question should have been; "How to obtain data from the database, and make it available to JavaScript, in .Net"

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a .NET based server-side integration for some tracking operations instead?

See Mixpanel.NET for example:

- [NuGet project](http://nuget.org/packages/Mixpanel.NET)
- [Github project](https://github.com/lucisferre/Mixpanel.NET)

It integrates with [Mixpanels's API](https://mixpanel.com/docs/).